# How to select everything but a specific pattern

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext2, selection

I am building a quick hack in sublimetext (yes, I know this is not optimal):

I have the following regex that selects all code within `<script></script>` tags:

```
<script[\s\S]*?\/script>
```

How can I select everything but this, i.e. the inverse of this / all code OUTSIDE `script` tags?

```
\\\code i want to select
 <script> code i don't weant to select</script>
/// code i want to select
```

I'd really appreciate examples both incluisve and exclusive of the `script` tags themselves.

Comment: When it comes to regular expressions, sometimes the easiest path is the best approach. You can try to write a complicated regex that will grab everything EXCEPT for the script tags, but it might be easier for you to grab everything first, and then use your working regex to simply strip out the script tags, leaving you with everything except the script tags.

Comment: Very true, how would I i) select all followed by ii) excluding my pattern in the same statement? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on DOTALL mode `(?s)` to make dot to match newline characters also.

```
(?s)^.*?(?=<script>)|(?<=<\/script>).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dN3kB4/7)

Answer (score -1):

There are many pitfalls using regex for html manipulation.

Consider for example this case:

```
<input type="text" value="<script> code i don't weant to select</script>" />
```

How do you handle this with a regex?

Therefore I would recommend to use an external library doing the parsing job for you. Google which ones are available in your programming language. Here are some I can recommend :

- Java: [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- Python: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to do this in regex

Comment: Yes this does not answer the question, but I want to point out that a regex in this case might cause some problems and therefore suggest an alternative.

Comment: @alias51 which language are you running?

Comment: @christophe, thanks this should probably go in comments.

Comment: @avinash, this is just a hack I am figuring out in sublimetext

Comment: 1 script tag, although the regex shown would pick them all up

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks, perfect but how do I exclude the tags in the selection?

Comment: sorry i don't know what do you mean by tag in the selection. Did you want to exclude the tags?